# NODEJS, GRAPHQL, SUBSCRIBE received multiple times instead of one

Tags: node.js, graphql, subscribe

SO basically, i have an app where when i receive a SMS, my back end catch it using graphql and then publish an event bus where all channel subscribe to this event bus received the notification real-time to the front end display.

My problem, is that my back end publish notification only once, but my front-end receives it much more often, like on a exponential scale. For exemple, the first notifications published is catched once. The second publish catches 2, then 4 8 etc...

I believe the reason is that the subscribe method front-end re-execute all the event from the event bus and executes the same one really often.

here is some code sample :

[image: Event published only once, for each new notifications]
[image: Received multiple event]

Here is the code that publishes the event : it adds the notification to my database and the publish an event to notify the browser to update.

```
function addNotification( from, to, body , date){
    //retrieve the last notifications received from this number to this number and crush it with this new notification
    let database = firebase.firestore();
    database.collection('notifications').where('from','==',from).where('to','==',to).get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {   
        if(querySnapshot.empty) {
            console.log('publish')
            let data = { from:from, to:to, body:body, date:date } 

             database.collection('notifications').doc().set(data)
             pubsub.publish(NOTIFICATIONS_ADDED, { notificationAdded: {from:from,to:to,body:body,date:date}});
        } else {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {  
                var data = {
                    body:body,
                    date:date
                }
                console.log('publish')
                database.collection("notifications").doc(doc.id).set(data, { merge: true }); 
                pubsub.publish(NOTIFICATIONS_ADDED, { notificationAdded: {from:from,to:to,body:body,date:date}});
            });
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        throw Error(err.toString());
      })
  }
```

Here is the code front-end which is subscribe to getNewNotificationSubscription

```
 _subscribeToMoreNotifications = subscribeToMore  => {
    subscribeToMore({
      document: getNewNotificationsSubscription,
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        console.log('received')
        if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev
        if (!subscriptionData.data.notificationAdded) return prev
        const newNotifications = subscriptionData.data.notificationAdded
        return  Object.assign({}, prev, {
          getSMSNotifications: [ newNotifications, ...prev.getSMSNotifications ]
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

I guess one workout around is to check if the last data received is the same than the one previously received, but it doesn't fix the problemm that i receives multiple times the same data.

Also, on my back end print screen, we can see **MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 NOTIFICATIONS_ADDED listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limitpublish** which doesn't looks good. however, i only have one listener to notifications_added.

Any idea what's going on ?